# Dumping multiple rows of dictionary into one row. Display it in a cell in pdf

Tags: c#, dictionary, pdf, itext

I am trying to insert the content of a dictionary say 3 rows into a single cell in a PDF formed by `iTextSharp`.

Can we collapse multiple rows into single row?

```
foreach (var pair in dictionaryActualJson)
{
    string value;

    if (dictionaryJsonFromExcel.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
    {
        if (value != pair.Value)
        {
            dictionaryActualJsonDifferences.Add(pair.Key, value);
            dictionaryJsonFromExcelDifferences.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);           
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, prog.dictionaryJsonFromExcelDifferences.ToList().ForEach(i).ToString() + 
                           "            :::             " + 
                           prog.dictionaryActualJsonDifferences.ElementAt(i).ToString() + 
                           System.Environment.NewLine);
```

but this is creating different cells

Answer (score 0):

Create a paragraph from each datarow and add those paragraphs to your single cell.